# How to Import YAML data into database in Ruby on Rails 3 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, import, yaml

I'm now working on a legacy Ruby on Rails project. I found the previous owner of this project exported data from Sqlite3 data tables to separate .yml files. Now I want to import these data from .yml files to their corresponding data tables, but didn't figure out how. The problem can be describe as:

1. Under the 'db' folder of Ruby on Rails 3 project root folder, there is a 'backup' folder that stores all the .yml files.

   (Rails 3 root folder)=>db=>backup=>(all the *.yml files)
2. Each .yml file corresponds to a data table in the database. For example, suppose I have a 'users' table, then I have a 'users.yml' file that stores several user data as the seeds.
3. The .yml file content is like:

   name: user1

   title: SE1

   location: loc1

   name: user2

   title: SE2

   location: loc2

If there anyone can help on this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely he used yaml_db gem. You can use

```
gem install yaml_db

rake db:data:load_dir dir='backup'
```

to load your data if that is the case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I installed the yaml_db, but when executing your second command, I got the following error: rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:data:load_dir'. Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: I made an error, it needs to be dir= 'backup' because the gem already works within the db dir. But I don't know what else could cause your error.

Comment: do you see a db:data:load_dir task when you execute rake -T ?